# C# Interface/Abstract Class with Dynamic Type

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I'm writing a series of math based class that each inherit from an abstract class.  I want my abstract class to have a getter and setter called Parameters.

```
public abstract dynamic Parameters {get; set;}
```

Then in each individual math class I want to implement Parameters with a certain type:

If the class requires a period I would do it like this:

```
public override IPeriod Parameters {get; set;}
```

This doesn't compile.  Obviously I could change the return type to `dynamic` and it would work, but then I lose intellisense.  Is there a standard way of doing this without losing intellisense?

Every one of the class will have a Parameters {get; set;} but they will be up a different type.  Is it better just to eliminate Parameters from the abstract class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, use generics..

```
public MyAbstractBaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract T Parameters {get; set;}
}
```

then you can inherit specifying the type that will be used for the param like..

```
public PeriodClass : MyAbstractBaseClass<IPeriod>
{
    public override IPeriod Parameters {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you make parameters a generic, you can return whatever type you want:

```
public abstract T Parameters<T> {get; set;}
```